# JavaScript template library that doesn't use eval/new Function

Tags: javascript, templates, google-chrome-extension, eval

Google Chrome extensions using `manifest_version: 2` are restricted from using `eval` or `new Function`. All of the JavaScript templating libraries I checked (mustachejs, underscorejs, jQuery template, hoganjs, etc) use `new Function`. Are there any that are fairly mature and supported that don't use either?

[Info about the security restrictions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538).

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that mustachejs added `new Function` recently and using [tag 0.4.2](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/tree/0.4.2) doesn't have it. It the API is slightly different with `Mustache.to_html` instead of `Mustache.render` and there are likely some performance reduction.

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/207) to potentially get `new Function` removed in a future release.

Comment: The solution to this is to use [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to precompile your mustache templates. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear that [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) uses either `eval` or `new Function`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I like the look of Pure but approach is very different from the more common template libraries. I'll be checking it out but it isn't really a solution without a pretty heavy rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here are outdated so I post an update.

Since September, Google changed their policy and allowed `unsafe-eval` in manifest 2 extensions. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-extensions/Wyer5m3Y4tQ) and [this page](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing-eval).

So libraries using `eval()`, `new Function()` etc. can be used if `unsafe-eval` is turned on for your extensions.

Comment: Note: That option isn't allowed for Chrome Apps (packaged apps), only for extensions.

Comment: The question is about extensions.

Comment: Right. Sometimes a feature added by Google for extensions is also there for Chrome Apps, and, seeing your answer, I went to check. I then added this additional information.

Answer (score 2):

[Closure Templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) is a templating library that does not use `eval`. Templates are compiled to JavaScript ahead of time, so that what gets included in your app is a plain .js file that should not run into CSP issues.

Answer (score 2):

[Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal) template doesn't use eval.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you mean by "template library". If you just want string interpolation, there's no need for `eval` or `new Function`, when you start needing embedded looping structures, things get more complicated.

A few months ago I wrote a [`String.prototype.tmpl.js` script](https://github.com/zzzzBov/jsoop/blob/master/String.prototype.tmpl.js) that I've used a couple times here and there in places where I don't mind overriding `String.prototype`. As a static function, you can use:

<sub>tmpl.js:</sub>

```
function tmpl(tmpl, o) {
    return tmpl.replace(/<%=(?:"([^"]*)"|(.*?))%>/g, function (item, qparam, param) {
        return o[qparam] || o[param];
    });
}
```

<sub>An example template:</sub>

```
<div id="bar"></div>
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="foo">
    <h1><%=title%></h1>
    <p><%=body%></p>
</script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var foo,
            bar;
        foo = document.getElementById('foo');
        bar = document.getElementById('bar');
        bar.innerHTML = tmpl(foo.innerHTML, {
            title: 'foo bar baz',
            body: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
        });
    }());
</script>
```

The base `tmpl` script can of course be modified to take advantage of document fragments to actually build out DOM elements, but as-is I'm not sure whether it counts as a "template library".

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this problem is to pre-compile your templates before you deploy your extension. Both [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco/) offer pre-compilation as a feature. I actually wrote a [blog post](http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2012/07/10/javascript-templates-and-chromes-content-security-policy/) that goes into more depth.

Comment: blog post no longer exists (404)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a function eval1:

```
function eval1(blah) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = blah;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
    document.head.removeChild(s);
}
```

and do a find/replace in the library you want, but that'd be cheating, right?

Answer (score 0):

I recently run into the same problem. After updating manifest version my extension stopped working. I tried Mustache but it unable to render index of the array and names of the object properties. So I had to create my own simple but effective templating library [Ashe](https://github.com/dfsq/Ashe) which is free of `eval` and `new Function`. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval

Not sure when it was added, but you can do Firefox style sandboxing in Chrome now. I'm porting my Firefox extension, so I need this (since I don't have evalInSandbox :P)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [Liquid](https://github.com/harttle/liquidjs) from Shopify, which did not trigger the CSP error.

By the way, Handlebars is giving the CSP error now.

I haven't tried the others.