# Javascript Template Engines that work with Chrome's Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, jaml

The Chrome API's Manifest version 2 has removed the ability to do unsafe-eval. This means using the eval function or in general dynamically creating a function from text.

It seems like most if not all Javascript Templating Engines do this. I was using Jaml, but I tried several others like backbone.js (which really uses underscore.js's templating engine) with no luck.

[This comment on the Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538#c35) seems to indicate that there are a great many libraries that suffer from this.

I think Angular.js has a CSP-safe mode, but Angular.js is really too big for what we need. We just need a fairly basic templating engine and don't need models or controllers and such. Does anyone know about any CSP-compatbility templating engines out there?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744764/javascript-template-library-that-doest-use-eval-new-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution to this problem is to pre-compile your templates before you deploy your extension. Both [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco/) offer pre-compilation as a feature. I actually wrote a [blog post](http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2012/07/10/javascript-templates-and-chromes-content-security-policy/) that goes into more depth.

Comment: Thanks this looks really promising, just need to look into it a bit more before approving.

Comment: Google already re-allows unsafe-eval for manifest 2. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13335364/17815

Answer (score 4):

You should absolutely use precompilation as recommended by Mathew for medium and big templates. For extremely small templates we are using this:

```
var template = function(message, data) {
  if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
    return _.partial(template, message);
  } else {
    return message.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)}}/g, function(s, match) {
      var result = data;
      _.each(match.trim().split('.'), function(propertyName) {
        result = result[propertyName]
      });
      return _.escape(result);
    });
  }
};

var data = {
  foo: 'Hello',
  bar: { baz: 'world!' }
};

// print on-the-fly
template('{{foo}}, {{bar.baz}}' args); // -> 'Hello, world!'

// prepare template to invoke later
var pt = template('{{foo}}, {{bar.baz}}');
pt(args); // -> 'Hello, world!'
```

This implementation does not use eval, but it will require underscore.

Comment: Underscore internally uses the `Function` constructor to compile the template, which is implicit `eval`. See https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/91632707/underscore.js#L1192-L1232

Comment: This implementation does not use the `_.template` method, which has the `eval` dependency (other underscore methods are fine). We are using it with a Content-Security-Policy and works nicely.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your last remark. I mistakenly interpreted it as "underscore's `_.template` does not use eval". You're absolutely correct: Your proposed implementation does not use `eval`.