# CSP-safe ES6 template literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, content-security-policy, template-strings

Is there a template engine that will parse templates in the style of [ES6 template literals](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components) (e.g. `"string ${var}"`) without violating a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) restriction on script evaluation?

The [CSP restrictions on script evaluation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#script-src) prevent `eval`, `new Function`, `setTimeout(string)` and `setInterval(string)`.

There are a number of template engines that can provide or be modified to provide something like ES6-style template literals, such as John Resig's [MicroTemplates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), lodash _.template and [DoT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/). However all seem to violate the CSP by using `new Function`.

It would in some ways be convenient if `var` could be unrestricted Javascript, but for apparent reasons this may not be possible. However I would need to be able to modify the engine to format the output as desired.

In the circumstances performance is not a concern, and pre-compiling the templates is not an option. Others have [discussed pre-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489495/javascript-template-engines-that-work-with-chromes-content-security-policy).

As an additional restriction, the content is text - not HTML. I do not think DOM-oriented templating engines such as Knockout or PURE would not work effectively, as a result.

My first thought is to start with [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) and modify it from there (i.e. change `mustache.tags = ['${', '}']` or a [DIY solution](http://www.angrycoding.com/2013/11/creating-your-own-template-engine-in.html), but I would be grateful for any thoughts on the topic in general as there seems to be quite a dearth of discussion on CSP and templates.

Comment: "In the circumstances performance is not a concern" -- string.replace with a callback then? callback can be as simple as `return vars[key];`.

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that ES6 templates are CSP-safe (but note that they do expose the site to scripting).

Comment: What do you mean by "*convenient if `var` could be unrestricted Javascript*"`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is key value substitution, you can make do with a simple function like the templateReplace that I provide below. No eval involved, only regular expressions.

If you need to include 'unrestriced javascript', have content like `${[1,2,3].join(', ')}` then, as you acknowledged, you will obviously need a solution that will violate your CSP policy.

```js
var templateReplace = function(html, data, keyTemplate) {
  if (!keyTemplate || typeof keyTemplate !== 'string' || keyTemplate.indexOf('key') === -1) {
    keyTemplate = '{{key}}';
  }
  return (Object.keys(data) || []).reduce(function(html, key) {
    var val = (data[key] !== undefined) ? data[key] : '';
    return html.replace(new RegExp(keyTemplate.replace('key', key), 'gi'), val);
  }, html);
};

// demo 1, using {{key}} syntax
(function() {
  var li = [{ text: 'one' }, { text: 'two' }, { text: 'three' }].map(function(d) {
    return templateReplace( '<li>Item: {{text}}</li>', d);
  });
  document.querySelector('#result1').innerHTML = li.join('\n')
}())

// demo 2, using ${key} syntax
(function() {
  var helloWorld = templateReplace('${hello} ${world}', { hello: 'Hello', world: 'World!' }, '\\${key}');
  document.querySelector('#result2').innerHTML = helloWorld;
}())
```

```html
demo 1 - {{key}} syntax
<div id="result1"></div>

demo 2 - ${key} syntax
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Micromustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micromustache) library does exactly that. version 6 supports setting custom open and close markers (`${` and `}` instead of `{{` and `}}`) which makes it more of a drop-in replacement for template literals.